# Filter dictionary based on list of keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary, join, filter

I have a dictionary `d = {'key1' : 1, 'key2' : 2, 'key3' : 3}`
and a list `lst = ['key1','key2']`

How do I filter the dictionary to only include keys in my list, such that I obtain `d = {'key1' : 1, 'key2' : 2}` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply:

```
d2 = {k:d[k] for k in lst}
```

But all keys must exist in the source directory. If not:

```
d2 = {k:d[k] for k in lst if k in d}
```

Comment: This is the most elegant and fastest solution, but will only work if every element in `lst` is also a key. From the OP it is unclear to me if that is the case.

Answer (score 2):

```
target_set = set(lst)
d2 = {k:v for k,v in d.items() if k in target_set}
```

```
d2
Out[23]: {'key1': 1, 'key2': 2}
```

Answer (score 2):

MrSoLoDoLo

try this,

```
data = [d[k] for k in list]
```

If you want to reconstruct a dictionary from the result, you can capture the keys as well in a list of tuples and convert to a dict, e.g.

```
data = dict ([(k, d[k]) for k in list])
```

Comment: I have edited my code.

Comment: on the first result simply you can convert into dictionary instead of a use list. => data = {d[k] for k in list}.

Answer (score 1):

```
dict(filter(lambda x: x[0] in lst, d.items()))
```